# Enviar dados de sensor para um banco

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, banco-de-dados

Olá, estou enviando os dados de um sensor para um site através da URL.

Quero transferir esses dados para um banco de dados SQL, e assim poder mostrá-los numa aplicação ASP.NET que fiz.

Alguém pode me informar como transferir esses dados da url pra database?

Comment: Podemos, desde que você dê mais informações sobre como você está fazendo. O que você já fez? Qual o problema que está tendo?

Comment: É um projeto na área de IoT. Por enquanto eu consigo enviar os dados do sensor para um site local atravéz da URL e tenho um banco de dados criado no SQL Server. Não sei como juntar os dois.
Eu li que talvez  pudesse utilizar um Web Service, mas n tenho certeza é assim que se faz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você esta na direção certa. Você pode criar uma aplicação Asp.Net MVC ou WebApi, nos dois você vai ter uma action que vai receber a requisição e gravar no banco de dados. Recomendo usar uma requisição do tipo POST pois há um limite (+- 2000 caracteres) no tamanho da requisição GET.